# Passing variables from docker build file to docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to pass a variable simply from docker build file to docker file, however the variable is never resolved

```
version: '3'
services:
    movie-discovery-server:
        container_name: movie-discovery-server
        build:
            args:
              PORT: 8761
            context: /Users/admin/Downloads/movie-discovery-server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: movie-discovery-server:latest
        environment:
          - PORT=8761
        expose:
            - 8761
```

And here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD ./target/movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ARG PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "--server.port=$PORT"]
```

however the $PORT is never resolved

---EDIT---
It turned out that I have made couple of mistakes in my files, I my answer below will contain the right file format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `ENTRYPOINT` nor `CMD` will resolve variables when json array format is used.

If you need to resolve the PORT either use an entrypoint script or use the shell form notation for `ENTRYPOINT`

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=$PORT
```

Comment: I have added the full correct format below for anyone to be able to find it

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was doing couple of things in the wrong way. For the docker compose file I introduced the following changes:

1. Removed the `args` tag as it had no effect
2. Replace the `expose` tag with `ports` tag, as the mapping was not working correctly

   ```
   version: '3'
   services:
     movie-discovery-server:
       container_name: movie-discovery-server
       build:
           context: /Users/admin/Downloads/movie-discovery-server
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
       image: movie-discovery-server:latest
       ports:
         - "8761:8761"
       environment:
         - PORT=8761
   ```

For the DockerFile, I have applied the advice I had from @codestation and let go with the JSON format

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD ./target/movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ARG PORT
ENTRYPOINT java -jar movie-discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=$PORT
```